# What Do You Call a Store that Sells Obsolete Equipment?

Tags: technical, technology

I think of the sort of place you could buy a power cord for a flip-phone ... and the word that comes to mind is 'radio shack'; not because of the company "Radio Shack"--which sells the same up-to-date equipment as anywhere else--but the old-time definition---a 'shack' where they would put together whatever old equipment they could find to get the job done.

"Radio Shack" sound good for 'modern use of obsolete equipment'?

Comment: The term "radio shack" already has an original meaning from before the chain of stores existed. [It was an old navy term for "radio room"](https://www.history.navy.mil/research/library/online-reading-room/title-list-alphabetically/t/terminology-and-nomenclature.html). The usage during WWII referred to primarily wooden structures on ships that housed their communications equipment.

Comment: There was a  common term for this in the US, 40-50 years ago.  But the term escapes me.

Comment: If the equipment is unused but obsolete, it might be sold by a **liquidator**.

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember!!  "Sears"!!

Answer (score 4):

*Surplus* shop or store. *Electronic surplus* would be more specific.

Started as Army Surplus but doesn't need to be.

Comment: Surplus implies an excess of items, rather than obsolescence.

Comment: @GArthurBrown -- Terms in English tend to reflect historical significance, not literal meaning.

Comment: There's a strong overlap between selling off things because they're obsolete and selling them off because you have more than you need.

Answer (score 2):

The commonly used term is [junk shop](https://www.google.com/search?q=defintion++%22junk+shop%22) (OL&G).

> "a shop selling secondhand goods or inexpensive antiques"

You can add "vintage electronics" to convey it sells a lot of obsolete electrical equipment.

Comment: @KannE It is however more narrow and appropriate than the other responses.

Comment: @KannE I don't know what JS or NC means.

Answer (score 2):

A *thrift shop* is a generic term for a store that sells used goods.

> Definition of thrift shop
> : a shop that sells secondhand articles and especially clothes and is often run for charitable purposes

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thrift%20shop

Most thrift shops specialize in clothing, furniture, household goods (kitchenware and the like), where the item sought is not specific. A specific item is more likely to be found on line, where a dealer may or may not have a particular item.